# Increasing total number of pinned projects of Intellij on Windows taskbar

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I pinned my Intellij on Windows taskbar.

Every time I need a project, I click right on the pinned Intellij symbol and open one of the last used projects.

I also pinned the last open projects in this small frame. But I have too many projects and I want to increase the number of them in order to navigate easily.  How can I do it?

[image: Pinned Intellij]

I tried open another project and pin it. But it did not allow. Total number of pinned projects are currently 13 but I would like to increase it to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an IntelliJ IDEA limitation, the limit is set in Windows registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

Add/change the following (DWORD 32-bit value):

`JumpListItems_Maximum`

- [How to Increase the Number of Jump List Items in Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+Increase+the+Number+of+Jump+List+Items+in+Windows)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I implemented this as you mentioned. It worked like a magic. Thank you very much.